# Prove that the map $\theta(f(\alpha))=f^\sigma(\beta)$ is injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm reading Lang's algebra chapter about Field theory and Galois theory. There is a theorem that says:

> Let $k$ be a field, $E$ an algebraic extension of $k$, and
>   $\sigma:k\to L$ an embedding into an algebraically closed field $L$.
>   Then there is an extension of $\sigma$ to an embedding of $E$ in $L$.

The proof uses Zorn' lemma but also uses the following (**I think**) to prove that the maximal element is indeed the desired embedding:

> If $E=k(\alpha)$ (The smallest field containing $k$ and $\alpha$),
>   $\alpha$ is algebraic over $k$ and $\sigma:k\to L$ is an embedding
>   into an algebraically closed field $L$ then there is an extension of
>   $\sigma$ to an **embedding** $\theta:k(\alpha)\to L$

Lang sets $\theta(f(\alpha))=f^\sigma(\beta)$ where $f\in k[X]$ and $\beta$ is a root of $f^\sigma$. I understand that such a map is well defined and an homomorphism but I can't see why it is injective (Lang's doesn't say so explicitly but his proof requires that $\theta$ be injective (I think))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Homomorphisms of fields are always injective provided you require $1$ to be sent to $1$. This is because fields have only trivial ideals, so the kernel must be $\{0\}$.

Comment: I don't know how I missed this detail, thanks.

Comment: @Zero No problem.